# Content type hub publishing

Tags: content-type-hub

When I publish a content type hub the following error occurs in Content type content type publishing error .

> [-2146233079] [System.InvalidOperationException] [There is an error in
>   XML document (2, 248).] 
>   *** Inner exception:  [-2146231999] [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException] [The
>   'AzureContainerSourceUri' attribute is not declared.]

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you manage to fix your issue? I just ran into the same issue.

Comment: Iam recreated MMS service and changed the site collection. For your issue is fixed ?